# Wicked Good X-Path, Internet Explorer (IE 9) & Namespaces

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, xmlhttprequest

I recently tried to include wgxpath for patching IE 9's lack of proper X-Path support but I'm getting a weird error message while trying to use namespaces («Error: Bad token: :»).

Have somebody tried to use it for XML documents got from XHR responses? I'm trying the following:

```
function evaluate(node, expression, namespaces) {
    var resolver = null;

    if(namespaces) {
        resolver = function(prefix) { return namespaces[prefix]; };
    }
    else if(document.createNSResolver) {
        resolver = document.createNSResolver(node);
    }

    var results = document.evaluate(expression, node, resolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

    var value = null;
    switch(results.resultType) {
        case XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE:
            value = results.numberValue;
            break;

        case XPathResult.STRING_TYPE:
            value = results.stringValue;
            break;

        case XPathResult.BOOLEAN_TYPE:
            value = results.booleanValue;
            break;

        case XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE:
        case XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE:
            value = [];
            var result = null;
            while(result = results.iterateNext()) {
                value.push(result);
            }
            break;

        case XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE:
        case XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE:
            value = [];
            for(var index = 0; index < results.snapshotLength; ++index) {
                value.push(results.snapshotItem(index));
            }
            break;

        case XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE:
        case XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE:
            value = results.singleNodeValue;
            break;
    }

    return value;
};
```

With IE, when evaluating "/svg:svg/svg:title/text()" on the XML document got from a static SVG file, it fails.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Also, I noticed it works properly with Chrome but not Firefox. I'm getting the following error message: «WrongDocumentError: Node cannot be used in a document other than the one in which it was created».

Since wgxpath installs on a window I'm not sure how I could set it up for incoming XHR XML documents...

Comment: What are you passing in for the `namespaces` argument? I.e. does `document.evaluate()` know about the `svg:` namespace prefix?

Comment: Also, not clear about the relationship between the two error messages you mentioned. WrongDocumentError occurs only in Firefox?

Comment: `namespaces` is `{"svg": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"}` and yes, "WrongDocumentError" is reported by Firefox. I highlighted it because perhaps this is something similar which happens to IE underneath: the expression is evaluated by calling the `evaluate` method of the HTML document object in lieu of the XML document got from the XHR and it doesn't like neither?

Comment: I have not used wgxpath, but what you say makes sense... the document from XHR is a different document from the HTML `document`. I don't know how you would install wgxpath on each incoming XHR document. You could copy the incoming XHR document into the html doc, but if they're big, that would be quite a waste. And there's the risk of HTML/XML differences interfering. However the cross-document issue doesn't explain the "bad token" error.